# Two Object in Firestore Referencing each other

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have 2 object stored in Firestore **Product** & **Shop**
And there maybe a lot of Product and Shop in the future, so I have Shop DocumentReference in Product and vise-versa

Here are how they look like

```dart
class Shop extends Equatable {
  final String? id;
  final String name;
  final List<Product?> shopProduct;
  final DateTime createDate;

...

static Future<Shop> fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) async {
    final data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    final shopProductRef = data['shopProduct'];

    final List<Product?> shopProductList;
    if (shopProductRef.isNotEmpty) {
      shopProductList = List.from(shopProductRef.map((ref) async {
        Product.fromDocument(await ref!.get());
      }));
    } else {
      shopProductList = [];
    }

    return Shop(
      id: doc.id,
      name: data['name'],
      shopProduct: shopProductList,
      createDate: (data['createDate'] as Timestamp).toDate(),
    );
  }
```

And

```dart
class Product extends Equatable {
  final String? id;
  final Shop shop;
  final double price;
  final String title;
  final DateTime date;

...

static Future<Product?> fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) async {
    final data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    final shopRef = data['shop'] as DocumentReference;
    final shopDoc = await shopRef.get();

      return Product(
        id: doc.id,
        shop: await Shop.fromDocument(shopDoc),
        price: data['price'],
        title: data['title'],
        date: (data['date'] as Timestamp).toDate(),
      );
  }
```

This is what I think should work in the first place but it brings up a problem that it is causing a loop since both are referencing each other.

I have come up a fix which is creating a second **fromDocument** method which skip the **shopProduct** or **Shop** when I am referencing it.

Is it the only / best way to do it?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Is there an error when you run this code?

Comment: Hi Frank. Lets say when I call Product.fromDocumemt, since it need to get Shop object, so it called Shop.fromDocument. Then Shop object need to get shopProduct, hence it call Product.fromDocument again, created a loop

Answer (score 1):

As I know you have two options

- First one is to add a document reference instead of referring to the classes

  something like this

```
class Product extends Equatable {
  final String? id;
  final DocumentRefrence<Shop> shop;
  final double price;
  final String title;
  final DateTime date;
...
```

and also do the same for `Shop` model

```
class Shop extends Equatable {
  final String? id;
  final String name;
  final List<DocumentReference<Product>?> shopProduct;
  final DateTime createDate;

...
```

- Second one is as you mentioned, create a method for `Product` model and name it for example: `Map<String, dynamic> toShopCollection()` and use it while setting a shop in firestore and also do the same for `Shop` model.

cm if you need more details